# Как добавить кнопку в Alert view на swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mobile-development

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть такая задача я хочу обработать две задачи на моем alert View первое в случаи если пользователь ввел пароль правильно ему показывали alert с кнопкой next.И при нажатии он переходил на другой экран.Я сделал сам alert View но не знаю как реализовать эту кнопку в alert View и ее действие. Второе я хочу обработать другое действие в случаи если пользователь ввел неправильно пароль то ему скидывали сообщение с надписью "Неправильно попробуйте еще".Я это тоже реализовал просто как сделать чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку мой textView становился пустым чтобы пользователю не пришлось заново набирать текст. Для наглядности я снял видео приложение вот ссылка: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTSh4SO3g6I

Comment: Дополните вопрос примером имеющегося кода чтоб было от чего отталкиваться.

Comment: Вот код добавил

Answer (score 1):

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Заголовок", message: "Сообщение", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
                            // обработка нажатия кнопки
                        })
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let tryAgain = UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: .destructive) { (action) in
        textView.text = ""
    }
```